# Desmume Lua issue

Tags: lua, notepad

Trying to get Rhythm Heaven ds to work on an emulator, which I have, but its really difficult to play because you have to flick, and getting the timing is really hard, especially with a mouse. Most of the rhythm games require high speed flicking. I found a code that lets the player easily swipe by pressing a key.
desmume lets you do Lua coding, which ive never used. I used notepad to paste all the code, and then turn the .txt into a .lua but for whatever reason BOM (Byte Order Mark) is in affect, which makes an invisible letter, but its still detected somehow.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWXvQ.png

I have no idea how to fix this. All I wanted to do was play Rhythm Heaven, and I never expected to have to do all this stuff. Thanks to anyone who figures this out

Comment: Can you show your Lua code in the question? (The image shows the path to the source file on your system, which doesn't do us any good.)

Comment: Lua doesn't support non-English symbols in identifiers.  Variable names must be English-only.  The error messages says that you have letter `ÿ` in the Lua program.  Such letters are allowed only inside string literals or comments.  Upload your Lua program.

Comment: It will be much easier to help you if you'll show us at least first line of code.

Comment: heres the first chunk of the code `; Apostrophe [ ' ] is used for any swipe outside of the title screen. I tried to reduce lag as much as possible.
'::
; SendMode Input
SetMouseDelay, -1
MouseMove, 291, 210
Click down
sleep 17
MouseMove, 291, 201
sleep 17
MouseMove, 291, 80
sleep 17
MouseMove, 291, 70
sleep 17
Click up
MouseMove, 294, 210
return`

Comment: @HoneyTart - That's not a Lua program.  Please upload your `C:\Users\Logan\Desktop\RythmHeavenSwipe.lua` file

Comment: Here ya go https://drive.google.com/open?id=12j_lw_v2xrpiDVyl1ij9WfYMKV1v04DY

Comment: I recommend you try and test this one on desmume itself to see if you can get it to work